# Firebase: do I need to send the uid everytime I post something in this case?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to restrict to allow a user only to read data he posted to firebase.
Auth is in place. Posting, reading and deleting data works just

But yet there weren't any real rules set to the firebase database.

I tried to change this like:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this gives me a 401 error (unauthorized). Now I am not sure what the problem might be. Do I maybe need to add the uid explicitly to the data send?
so firebase can try to match uid from the post and the auth.uid.

But I have the feeling this wouldn't secure the data sufficient.

EDIT:
some of the code I am using:

data.service.ts

```
  storeNotes() {
    const notes = this.noteService.getNotes();
    this.http
      .put(
        'https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/notes.json',
        notes
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

note.service.ts

```
private notes: Note[] = [];

getNotes() {
    return this.notes.slice();
  }
```

note.model.ts

```
export class Note {
  public userName: string;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;


  constructor(userName: string, name: string, desc: string) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
  }
}
```

I haven't posted the auth data now, since I don't think, they should be relevant here. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You tagged with `google-cloud-firestore`, but the security you show are for the Firebase Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the security rules for one don't apply to the other. If you're using Cloud Firestore, be sure to set the correct rules for that database.

Comment: You should also show the app code that queries the database that would be affected by these rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay, I see my mistake there. Thanks!

Comment: @DougStevenson Just did that.

Answer (score 0):

Your security rules only allow access to data under "users/{uid}", but your query writing children under "notes".  You have no rules that allow access to that.

Either you will have to add a rule to allow access to "notes", or you are accessing the wrong location in your database.  If you want to store per-user data under the "users/{uid}", then you should build that into the path of your URL as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database), for example `/users/{uid}/notes`

Comment: Thank you. Yes that seems almost obvious now... Did not look close enough on that code. How would you solve this in my case specifically? I just changed the users/{uid} into notes/{uid} but didnt help.

Comment: I don't know.  You will have to decide for yourself what you want you are trying to accomplish.  It's up to you to structure your database in a way that meets the needs of your app.

Comment: I looked into the docs but am still unsure. What I did was replacing "users" with "notes". That should be the right thing. But it somehow is not. I dont understand why.